# Error: Tensorflow Op is not supported: AddN

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow.js

I've retrained a Mobilenet V1 model using my own dataset. Right now, I'm trying to get my model to load into this example project:
https://github.com/shivangidas/image-classifier

It keeps throwing the following error

```
 Error: Tensorflow Op is not supported: AddN
```

I don't understand what this means or why this error is being shown. I also can't seem to find anything about it online.

This is the code I'm using:

```
const MODEL_URL =
  "https://localhost/path/to/model";
const WEIGHTS_URL =
  "https://localhost/path/to/weights_manifest";
let model;
let IMAGENET_CLASSES = [];
let offset = tf.scalar(128);
async function loadModelAndClasses() {
  $.getJSON(
   "https://localhost/path/to/labels.json",
    function(data) {
      $.each(data, function(key, val) {
        IMAGENET_CLASSES.push(val);
      });
    }
  );
  model = await tf.loadFrozenModel(MODEL_URL, WEIGHTS_URL);
  //console.log("After model is loaded: " + tf.memory().numTensors);
  $(".loadingDiv").hide();
  $("#inputImage").attr("disabled", false);
}
loadModelAndClasses();
function readURL(input) {
  if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
    var reader = new FileReader();

reader.onload = function(e) {
  $("#imageSrc")
    .attr("src", e.target.result)
    .width(224)
    .height(224);
};

reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
//console.log("After image is loaded: " + tf.memory().numTensors);

reader.onloadend = async function() {
  console.log("Before predictions: " + tf.memory().numTensors);

  let imageData = document.getElementById("imageSrc");

  //console.log("After offset: " + tf.memory().numTensors);
  let pixels1 = tf.fromPixels(imageData);
  let pixel2 = pixels1.resizeNearestNeighbor([224, 224]);
  let pixel3 = pixel2.toFloat();
  console.log("After pixels are formed: " + tf.memory().numTensors);

  let pixels = pixel3.sub(offset);
  let pixels4 = pixels.div(offset);
  let pixels5 = pixels4.expandDims();
  console.log("After pre-processing: " + tf.memory().numTensors);

  const output = await model.predict(pixels5);
  console.log("After output: " + tf.memory().numTensors);
  const predictions = Array.from(output.dataSync())
    .map(function(p, i) {
      return {
        probabilty: p,
        classname: IMAGENET_CLASSES[i]
      };
    })
    .sort((a, b) => b.probabilty - a.probabilty)
    .slice(0, 10);

  //console.log(predictions);
  var html = "";
  for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    html += "<li>" + predictions[i].classname + "</li>";
  }
  $(".predictionList").html(html);
  console.log("After predictions: " + tf.memory().numTensors);

  pixels.dispose();
  pixels1.dispose();
  pixel2.dispose();
  pixel3.dispose();
  pixels4.dispose();
  pixels5.dispose();
  output.dispose();
  console.log("After dispose: " + tf.memory().numTensors);
     };
    }
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `addN` operation is supported by the converter according to [this list](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/blob/master/tfjs-converter/docs/supported_ops.md). It looks like you are using a rather old version of Tensorflow.js. I noticed the function `loadFrozenModel` which has been renamed to `loadGraphModel` since version 1.0 (released in March 2019).

Converting `addN` is supported [since version 0.5.6](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-converter/blob/v0.5.6/docs/supported_ops.md) (see [this commit](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-converter/commit/d7427eb84df7bc05c9254010719d7fd416ef8b4c#diff-86b322812e9000253eed437a8b196c3f)). If your Tensorflow.js version is older than `0.5.6` you can simply upgrade to a more recent version and it should work.

Comment: Thank you! The example code I used was indeed using an older (0.12.0) version of TensorflowJS. Changed it to version 1.0.0 and the error is gone now.